# How to quantity increase decrease with input number with mapping all separate product id in react js

Tags: reactjs

How to quantity increase decrease with input number with mapping all separate product IDs in react js?

```
[    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Kitchen Refrigerator (inc in Premium & Ultimate plans)",
        "price": "4.16"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Enhanced External Pipe Coverage",
        "price": "8.33"

    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Air Conditioning (additional unit)",
        "price": "7.08"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Additional Washer Dryer (1 set incl in Ultimate Plans)",
        "price": "7.08"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your mean , if not Please explain more

```
const [value , setValue] = useState()
const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([])

const items = [{
        id: 15,
        name: "Kitchen Refrigerator (inc in Premium & Ultimate plans)",
        price: "4.16"
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        name: "Enhanced External Pipe Coverage",
        price: "8.33"

    },
    {
        id: 17,
        name: "Air Conditioning (additional unit)",
        price: "7.08"
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        name: "Additional Washer Dryer (1 set incl in Ultimate Plans)",
        price: "7.08"
    }
]

const removeItem = () => {
 setNewItems(items.filter(i => i.id !== value))
}

<input onChange={(e)=> setValue(e.target.value)} />
<button onClick={()=> removeItem() />
```