# State setter, that useState hook returns, doesn't re-render the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have functional component `TaskManager`, which uses `useState` hook to hold the state.

```
const TaskManager = () => {
  const [sections, setSections] = useState({
    sectionArr: [{}, {}, {}],

    taskArr: [...],
  });

  return(
    ...
  );
};
```

And from `TaskManager` I pass my `setSections` func to the daughter component `DeleteSectionButton`

```
function DeleteSectionButton({ sectionID, sections, setSections }) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    const updatedSectionArr = sections.sectionArr.filter(
      (sect) => sect.id !== sectionID
    );
    const updatedState = sections;
    updatedState.sectionArr = updatedSectionArr;

    setSections(updatedState);
  };
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

So that I update the `TaskManager`'s state via `setSections`. But the `TaskManager` component doesn't actually re-render after I use `setSections`, which is strange to me. However if I console.log the state of `TaskManager` - I see that it actually changes. So why `setSections` doesn't cause the re-render of `TaskManager`?

Btw: `DeleteSectionButton` changes the state in next way - it removes one of the elements from `sectionArr` array and that's it. It doesn't affect the value of `sectionArr` directly. May this be related to this strange behaviour? Because when I put something completely different as an argument to `secSections` (0 for instance) - then `TaskManager` re-renders normally.

Comment: You can see this link I think it will help you ---
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002755/14448593

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mutating the same prop object that you are getting from the parent, return a new object to `setSections`.

```
const handleClick = () => {
    const updatedSectionArr = sections.sectionArr.filter(
      (sect) => sect.id !== sectionID
    );

    setSections({ ...sections, sectionArr: updatedSectionArr });
};
```

this will return new object reference each time to `setSections`.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case,

```
const updatedState = sections;
    updatedState.sectionArr = updatedSectionArr;
    setSections(updatedState)
```

As you aren't creating a new object here, but passing the same object reference to the setter function, react doesn't re-render the component.
In JavaScript, the object is passed by reference and since both objects point to the same location in memory, React does not interpret it as a new state and does not render it again.

```
const updatedState = {
  sectionArr: updatedSectionArr,
  taskArr: sections.taskArr,
};
setSections(updatedState);
```

In this case, since you passed a new object, it points to a new location in memory which react treats as a new state, which caused the component to be re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Well, experimentally I found out that this works:

```
    const updatedState = {
      sectionArr: updatedSectionArr,
      taskArr: sections.taskArr,
    };

    setSections(updatedState);
```

Not this:

```
    const updatedState = sections;
    updatedState.sectionArr = updatedSectionArr;

    setSections(updatedState);
```

But any more detailed explanation on this mechanics would be apprecialed